# Segmentation fault before main when using key args

Tags: c, linux

I get a segmentation fault before `main()` when I try to start with command `./somename.o -s 4`

Works well when using `./somename.o` without key arguments

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "input.h"
#include "output.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    input_handler(argc, argv);
    pretty_print();
    return 0;

}
```

input.h

```
#include "data.h"
#include"func.h"

#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void input_handler(int argc, char** argv);
```

data.h

```
#pragma once
void(*func) (void);
void(*input) (void);
static struct Matrix {
    int size;
    int** A;
}matrix;
```

GitHub:

https://github.com/sandderson/lab2

EDIT:
added include guards
Also some usefull info:
I use windows subsystem for linux
I compile with makefile and following sequence:

```
gcc -c func.c
gcc -c input.c
gcc  -c main.c
gcc  -c output.c
gcc main.o func.o input.o output.o -o Lab2.o
```

Comment: What does `input_handler()` do?

Comment: How exactly do you compile your code?

Comment: What makes you think that the segfault is before main? Did you run it with a debugger? (If so, it might be helpful to show the debugging session.)

Comment: @DYZ input_handler handles key arguments and allocates matrix.A

Comment: @dbush via makefile
 gcc -c func.c
gcc -c input.c
gcc  -c main.c
gcc  -c output.c
gcc main.o func.o input.o output.o -o Lab2.o

Comment: @sandders_on Add that to your question.  It's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @rici I put printf on the beginning of main and I get  segmentation fault only. Also I use windows subsystem for Linux, so I cant debug it propperly

Comment: @dbush I don't have enough reputation to edit

Comment: @sandders_on You can always edit your own posts.

Comment: regarding your 'home grown' header files:  1) strongly suggest avoiding `#pragma once`  2) do use 'include guards' like: `#ifndef FUNC_H` `#define FUNC_H` at the beginning of the file, then at the end of the file: `#endif // FUNC_H`

Comment: @dbush cant find where and how

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the contents of some of the header files AND `#pragma once` , if used instead of 'include guards', must be at the beginning of each header file,

Comment: @sandders_on Click the "edit" link at the bottom of the question, just under the tags.

Comment: these command line arguments: `-s 4` are only worked with by the function: `input_handler()`  so we MUST see that function body otherwise we will be unable to help you

Comment: a windows system running on linux can be debugged with the WinDbg utility

Comment: @user3629249 added include guards - nothing changed. Also I cant add input handler because its to much code

Comment: OT:  It is best to only include header files where they are needed.  For instance in the header file: `input.h` there is NO need for any included header files. (those includes should be at the top of the source files that use the contents of those header files.

Comment: regarding: `void(*func) (void);
void(*input) (void);`  these are instances of data (function pointers)  It is fraught with peril to place data instances in header files.  It is a very good idea to place data definitions and function prototypes in header files

Comment: regarding: `Also I cant add input handler because its to much code`  Then suggest placing that file somewhere that we can access it and letting us know where the 'somewhere' is located.  BTW: suggest adding a EDIT section to your question where you post all the latest versions of each your other files

Comment: @sandders_on: printf is a notoriously bad way of establishing a sequence of events, since the message doesn't appear on stdout until the stdio buffer gets flushed. If you didn't put a newline in your output, for example, the line almost certainly was still in the buffer when the program segfaulted.

Comment: @rici I know it, I do it, but for now I cant. imagine me using only notepad and terminal to make it work

Comment: @user3629249 ok, added project on github

Comment: @sandders_on Remove any code that you don't need to replicate the error. Then update your question with precisely the remaining code. If you *can* replicate the problem without `input_hander`, then take that code out completely. If you *can't* replicate the problem without `input_handler`, then we need it because the bug might be there.

Comment: WHERE on github?  please post a link

Comment: regarding: ``  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `getopt_long` uses `"sdi"` as the options string, which means that `-s`, `-d` and `-i` are possible options, and that none of them take an argument (since none are followed by a colon). See [`man getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) for details.

But when you are handling the `-s` option, you do:

```
matrix.size = atoi(optarg);
```

which assumes `optarg` will be set up to point to an argument. It isn't, because as far as `getopt_long` is concerned, `-s` doesn't take an argument. Thus, it has its initial value (`NULL`) and `atoi` attempts to use that as a string. Unsurprisingly, a segmentation fault results.

Moreover, your attempt to bracket the error by inserting `printf` calls fails because you have failed to ensure that the `printf` is flushed to the actual output device. Stdio buffering makes `printf` a notoriously inaccurate tool for demonstrating the sequence of actions inside a program; you really cannot assume that an error preceded a call to `printf` just because the output from the `printf` was not visible.

Ideally, you should do both of the following (although either one would be sufficient in most cases):

1. Send debugging output to `stderr` using fprintf
2. Terminate debugging lines with a newline character

Eg: `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "dlfkg");`, although you could use a better message.

(Even if you do that, it is possible that the line output to the terminal is overwritten or otherwise fails to be presented as a result of a segfault which occurs soon afterwards. But your odds of seeing the message are a lot better.)

But if you neither of those things, then the most likely outcome is that the characters printed will only be placed in the `stdio` buffer, where they will stay until the buffer becomes full or a newline is printed (if the device is line-buffered, for which there is no guarantee). When the program blows up as a result of the segfault, the stdio buffers vanish into thin air, so nothing ever gets printed. Thus the non-appearance of the line tells you precisely nothing about the sequence of events.

The small amount of extra typing would have been a lot less than asking this question here and responding to the resulting comments. Just sayin'